# Log file not updated

Tags: configuration, logging

I am running Sitecore 9 and am experiencing moments when the Sitecore log is no longer updated (i.e. written to).

I have a default log4net configuration. Only addition I have is a rolling log file appender:

```
<appender name="StaticFileAppenderTxt" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
    <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/_Log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1000KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
```

But this seems unrelated to the problem as the "normal" log file is also not updated.

Only solution I found so far is performing an IISReset. This is clearly unconvenient.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963735/log4net-rollingfileappender-not-flushing-io-buffer-with-low-volume-log

Comment: Is there any information in the windows event viewer?

Comment: No, nothing related in the windows event viewer. Trying the ImmediateFlush parameter.

Comment: Im having same issue in Sitecore 8.1 update 2 solution. basically rollingappender is not working for me.

Comment: @Joost.. I just found out that in my case log files are being created at root of my c drive (c:\data\logs\..).. Please check if this is the case with you.

Comment: The ImmediateFlush parameter does seem to solve it! (testing it a bit more since the issue sporadically occurs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding:

`<param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />`

to the configuration, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963735/log4net-rollingfileappender-not-flushing-io-buffer-with-low-volume-log.